# how to create watermark background in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

hello 
i want to create watermark background in crystal report.
one way is:
1- On the Report menu, click Section Expert.

The Section Expert dialog box appears.
2- In the Sections list, click Page Header, then select the Underlay Following Sections check box. 
3- Click OK to preview the report again.

but in this solution lines and boxes in report design page appear back of background image.
what is better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your method is the best way to do it, as far as I know.

On your background don't forget to **right-click->move->to back**.  That should put the background image in the back and all other report elements in the front.

Comment: thanks, but this menu is appear in details section. and set my background in header section. also i am do this work ( right-click->move->to back) but still box element in top of background image.

Answer (score 1):

the solution to this problem is make a subreport, the main report will only have the watermark on page header A, and the subreport on page header B